# Getting a lot of TypeScript errors after running Ionic project on MacOs

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have developed an Ionic app and it is working fine on windows. I am running MacOs El Capitan on VirtualBox. I have setup everything on MacOs, but when i try to run the app using Ionic Serve I get many typescript errors which i don't  get on windows.

I searched a lot of solutions but none of them fixed my issue.

**These are the errors**

> [app-scripts] [03:55:07]  typescript:
>   node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts, line: 138 [app-scripts]
>   ';' expected. [app-scripts]      L138:      function
>   createSpyObj(methodNames: SpyObjMethodNames): any; [app-scripts]
>   L139:      function createSpyObj(methodNames: SpyObjMethodNames):
>   SpyObj; [app-scripts]             '(' expected. [app-scripts]
>   L138:      function createSpyObj(methodNames: SpyObjMethodNames): any;
>   [app-scripts] [03:55:07]  typescript:
>   node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts, line: 138 [app-scripts]
>   [03:55:07]  typescript: node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts, line:
>   138 [app-scripts]      L139:      function
>   createSpyObj(methodNames: SpyObjMethodNames): SpyObj;
>   [app-scripts]             ']' expected. [app-scripts]      L138:
>   function createSpyObj(methodNames: SpyObjMethodNames): any;
>   [app-scripts]      L139:      function createSpyObj(methodNames:
>   SpyObjMethodNames): SpyObj; [app-scripts]             ',' expected.
>   [app-scripts]      L138:      function createSpyObj(methodNames:
>   SpyObjMethodNames): any; [app-scripts]      L139:      function
>   createSpyObj(methodNames: SpyObjMethodNames): SpyObj;
>   [app-scripts]             Property assignment expected. [app-scripts] 
>   L138:      function createSpyObj(methodNames: SpyObjMethodNames): any;
>   [app-scripts]      L139:      function createSpyObj(methodNames:
>   SpyObjMethodNames): SpyObj; [app-scripts]             ')' expected.
>   [app-scripts]      L138:      function createSpyObj(methodNames:
>   SpyObjMethodNames): any; [app-scripts] [03:55:07]  typescript:
>   node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts, line: 138 [app-scripts]
>   [03:55:07]  typescript: node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts, line:
>   138 [app-scripts] [03:55:07]  typescript:
>   node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts, line: 138 [app-scripts]
>   [03:55:07]  typescript: node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts, line:
>   138 [app-scripts] [03:55:07]  typescript:
>   node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts, line: 138 [app-scripts]
>   [03:55:07]  typescript: node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts, line:
>   138

Answer (score 2):

Reinstall your app script using below command

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

and run the below command also

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

and run your project it will work fine

```
ionic serve
```

Comment: then remove your node_modules and reinstall it using npm install

Comment: Fixed it. Installed @types/jasmine 
Thank you for your response!